# Why its just printing today's date and not last five years date

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why it's printing only todays date and not last five years date ?

```
    from datetime import date
    from datetime import timedelta
    today = date.today()
    for i in range(1826):
        res = today - timedelta(days=i)
        f1 = res.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
        f2 = res.strftime("%m-%d-%y")
        f3 = res.strftime("%d-%b-%y")
        f4 = res.strftime("%d-%B-%Y")
    print(f1)
    print(f2)
    print(f3)
    print(f4)
```

Output

```
05-08-2012
08-05-12
05-Aug-12
05-August-2012
```

Comment: because your print statements are outside your for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your `print` functions into the loop:

```
for i in range(1826):
    res = today - timedelta(days=i)
    f1 = res.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    f2 = res.strftime("%m-%d-%y")
    f3 = res.strftime("%d-%b-%y")
    f4 = res.strftime("%d-%B-%Y")
    print(f1)
    print(f2)
    print(f3)
    print(f4)
```

Though you can instead:

```
for i in range(1826):
    res = today - timedelta(days=i)
    print(res.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
    print(res.strftime("%m-%d-%y"))
    print(res.strftime("%d-%b-%y"))
    print(res.strftime("%d-%B-%Y"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the print functions inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your print statements are not indented in the for loop, so you are only getting the last result.